# asterisk queue_log late COMPLETEAGENT

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to write a wallboard for my asterisk server. This wallboard will process the queue_log file in /var/log/asterisk.

Here is a scenario in question:

1) A customer calls out call center. Let his number be 44556677889900 and our number 8881234567890.

2) The customer enters the queue 210.

3) Agent 1 takes the call.

4) Agent 1 decides that the call should go to another queue. And transfers it to queue 209

5) Agent 2 takes the call.

6) Agent 2 terminates the call after talking with the customer. (When Agent 2 is talking on the phone Agent 1 is idle and available for a new call.

7) Normally Agent 1 ended his call at 4th step, but the log with COMPLETEAGENT appears just now, even the agent is available since 4th step

Here is the output in the queue_log:

1550582529|1550582516.26480|210|NONE|DID|8881234567890    *** 1. step***
1550582529|1550582516.26480|210|NONE|ENTERQUEUE||44556677889900|1  *** 2. step***
1550582531|1550582516.26480|210|Test Agent 1|CONNECT|2|1550582529.26493|2 **3. step**
1550582536|1550582536.26498|209|NONE|DID| ** 4. step**
1550582536|1550582536.26498|209|NONE|ENTERQUEUE||**9991**|1 **4. step**
1550582539|1550582536.26498|209|Test Agent 2|CONNECT|3|1550582536.26499|2 **5. step**
1550582543|1550582536.26498|209|Test Agent 2|COMPLETECALLER|3|4|1 **6. step**
1550582549|1550582516.26480|210|Test 1|COMPLETEAGENT|2|18|1 **7. step**

As mentioned in the 7th step, Agent 1 if available for new calls after he transfers the call to queue 209. (In fact if a new call comes, the system send the call to Agent 1). However the log "COMPTELEAGENT" appears only when the customer disconnects.

This makes my wallboard think that Agent 1 is busy even he is not. And worse if he received a new call before Agent 2 finishes, everything gets more complicated.

Questions:

1) How it is possible to make the system send the COMPLETEAGENT at step 4 ?

2) Why is ATTENDEDTRANSFER log missing ? (Not related to this problem directly but can also be connected)

Asterisk Version: 13.22.0

Freepbx 14.0.5.25

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) System should not send COMPLEATEAGENT at 4, becuase thoose event should be sent AFTER END  of call.
That event is created by QUEUE, not by AGENT. From queue's point of view call not yet finished.

If you want it be finished,  do transfer of LEGA, not queue's LEG.

2)Transfer subsystem not related to queue subsystem and SHOULD NOT be related in any realible PBX. You can write your own if you want.

Side notes

- no point parse queue_log, much simpler setup queue_log in mysql or other db and read it.
- you can write your own queue system using Async AGI.
- you can add as many logs as you want by using dialplan CEL or UserEvents.